# C-Stick not staying enabled

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

Every time I start up MH4U the option to enable the Circle Pad Pro is disabled.
If I go to the options and enable it the C-Stick stays active until returning to the main menu.

Is there a way to make the C-Stick stay enabled? I forget a fair bit and it gets messy when i spawn in front of a Deviljho and realise I only have D-pad camera control.

I have used the C-Stick normally with two other games without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried it with other games?

Comment: Yes forgot to mention that, it works fine in the 2 other games i have that use the C-Stick

Comment: Before you start up your DS, either from suspend (opening the lid), or powering it up, do you press a button on the CPP?  I find MH4U is a bit pickier in this regard and the CPP needs to be activated before the system.

Comment: I'm not using the actual circle pad pro peripheral, I am using the C-Stick that is built into the New 3DSXL

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/71354445):

> You still have to activate it in the game options before you load your save. If you just activate it in game, you have to do this every time.

Since the alternative behavior matches up with your situation, it seems like this is the culprit. You just need to activate it in the main menu rather than in the menu once you load your file.